# What is a good stretchy bind-off for 2:2 ribbing?

Tags: knitting

I knitted a hat top-down with a stranded 2:2 rib edge. What would be an nice-looking and adequately stretchy bind-off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a variation of Jeny’s Surprisingly Stretchy Bind-Off (JSSBO) [explained here over at Knitty.com.](http://knitty.com/ISSUEfall09/FEATjssbo.php) An additional resource for this technique is this drawing [provided by Interweave:](https://www.interweave.com/article/knitting/jenys-surprisingly-stretchy-bind-off/) [image]

The drawing demonstrates the JSSBO technique in a k2:p1 ribbing pattern.  To use JSSBO for binding-off a k2:p2 ribbing, such as the one shown below, simply apply the knit-type and purl-type techniques described in Step 1–>Step 2 in corresponding fashion upon the k2:p2 stitches of the ribbing.  (Therefore you could use this bind-off on any ratio of ribbing!)

As you can see it is a nice looking bind off:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is always the bind-off that I use for stretchy patterns :)